# Is spark.read.text an action?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

Is spark.read.text a Spark action or a transformation?

My understanding is that it is a transformation. But then why does this takes 3 minutes 25 seconds in my Zeppelin notebook?

```
val dump = spark.read.text(s"s3://redacted/*/*").as[String].filter(_.nonEmpty)
```

There are no actions in this pipeline, only transforms. This cell of my Apache Zeppelin notebook should execute instantly. Is it because it enumerates all files in my S3 bucket?

For context: Spark version = 3.0.0-amzn-0, Zeppelin version 0.9.0-preview1.

Answer (score 0):

It is neither an Action or Transformation.

Spark uses 'lazy' evaluation and as such read cannot be like ‘save’, an Action. filter is a Transformation.

Spark also with Catalyst (DFs, etc.) launches some underwater optimization in certain cases.

I ran to refresh some code on the Databricks S3 locations. Bear in mind there are issues with speed for S3 and it is not a posix like file system with quick finding of locations.

This `val dump = spark.read.text("/mnt/training/*.csv")` runs in a jiffy and no Job initiated.

This `val dump = spark.read.text("/mnt/training/")` generates a Job with description as follows:

```
Listing leaf files and directories for 58 paths:
dbfs:/mnt/training/301, ...
```

This latter is similar to your .../* /*.

As S3 is slow, something is kicking in to find files locations already (that you specified), so as to compensate for slowness and as you are in synchronous mode you have to wait.

The prose on the Internet on Action and Transformation is by and large all based on RDDs but things have moved on what with the introduction of DFs and DSs.

None the less read cannot be seen as Action and I am sure the filter is not yet applied. I see no bytes in and out on the Spark UI.

Comment: It does not seem "lazy" since this line takes over 3 minutes to execute.

It seems like the Spark is actually reading all the S3 files in my bucket. Which is strange, because I'd expect it to read the files only when some Action is executed down the line.